# Count in where clause or subquery calculation in select

Tags: mysql, where-clause, calculated-columns

I have a table `story`, which contains an `id` and a `title`. Users can vote up or down for each story. Here is the model:

```
+-------+      +----------+
| Story |      |   vote   |
+-------+~~~~~~+----------+
| id    |      | id       |
| title |      | story_id |
+-------+      | type     |
               +----------+
```

`type` is a `boolean`.
I would like to fetch stories with a difference between upvote and downvote > 1. And I also would like to know how many upvotes the story got. To sum up, this is an example of the result I'm trying to get:

```
+----------+---------+------------+------------+
| story_id | title   | difference | nb_upvotes |
+----------+---------+------------+------------+
| 1        | title 1 | 5          | 45         |
| 4        | title 4 | 32         | 89         |
| 5        | title 5 | 18         | 12         |
+----------+---------+------------+------------+
```

I've tried this

```
SELECT s.id,
       s .title,
       Count(v.id) AS upvote
FROM   story s
       INNER JOIN vote mp
               ON v.story_id = s.id
                  AND v.type = 1
WHERE  (SELECT Count(id) up
        FROM   vote
        WHERE  type = 1
               AND story_id = s.id) - (SELECT Count(id) down
                                       FROM   vote
                                       WHERE  type = 0
                                              AND story_id = s.id) > 0
GROUP  BY s.id;
```

But I don't get the difference in the results. Only the number of upvotes:

```
+----------+---------+------------+
| story_id | title   | nb_upvotes |
+----------+---------+------------+
| 1        | title 1 | 45         |
| 4        | title 4 | 89         |
| 5        | title 5 | 12         |
+----------+---------+------------+
```

How could I achieve this ?

Thanks

EDIT:

Thanks to @miken32 I got it to work with this

```
SELECT id, title,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM story_moderation WHERE story_id = s.id AND type = 1) AS upvotes,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM story_moderation WHERE story_id = s.id AND type = 0) AS downvotes,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM story_moderation WHERE story_id = s.id AND type = 1) - (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM story_moderation WHERE story_id = s.id AND type = 0) as diff
FROM story s
HAVING upvotes - downvotes > 0
```

But this is a lot of subqueries, isn't it too resource consuming?

Comment: Providing the result that you're trying to get without providing the data set that might provide is next to useless. I'm trying to make eleven out of two other numbers. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you want something in your result set, it needs to be mentioned in your `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without anything to test on, but does this do the trick? If you want to capture any info in the result set, it has to be specified in your `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT id, title,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM vote WHERE story_id = s.id AND type = 1) AS upvotes,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM vote WHERE story_id = s.id AND type = 0) AS downvotes
FROM story s
HAVING upvotes - downvotes NOT IN (-1, 0, 1);
```

Comment: thanks I made it work based on your answer, and I edited my question. I'm afraid this will be too resource consuming

Comment: You wanted an SQL solution, you got it — question answered. It might be more effective, based on your environment, indexes, number of rows, etc to pull all the records and process the results.

Comment: I didn't forget, I was just busy :)